# Combine multiple array with one array key

Tags: php, arrays, array-combine

I have a situation in PHP where I need to combine multiple array values and bind with the first array key, Let say I have following array,

```
[services] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [package_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [service_desc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Full HD
            [1] => Full HD
            [2] => Full HD
        )

    [service_price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 500
            [1] => 600
            [2] => 500
        )
```

Now , I want to bind all array with service type keys like services[0] will have the value of package_type[0],  service_desc[0] and service_price[0]. The purpose is that I can easily identify all service related values with its Id. Can anyone suggest ?

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far ?

Comment: Use array_merge function 
https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_merge.php

Answer (score 0):

`array_map` is key here.  Leave the first argument as null and it will group as you want:

```
<?php

$data = 
[
    'services' =>
    [
        'programming',
        'debugging'
    ],
    'description' => 
    [
        'the process of writing computer programs.',
        'the process of identifying and removing errors from software/hardware'
    ]
];

$result = array_map(null, $data['services'], $data['description']);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'programming',
    1 => 'the process of writing computer programs.',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'debugging',
    1 => 'the process of identifying and removing errors from software/hardware',
  ),
)
```

Instead of writing out all your keys as arguments you could unpack like this:

```
array_map(null, ...array_values($data));
```

For something more elaborate, pass `array_map` a callable:

```
$keys   = array_keys($data);
$result = array_map(function(...$args) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $args);
}, ...array_values($data));

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'services' => 'programming',
    'description' => 'the process of writing computer programs.',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'services' => 'debugging',
    'description' => 'the process of identifying and removing errors from software/hardware',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this.